# Chrome Geolocation access to home network 192.168 via HTTP[noS]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

Chrome allows Geolocation API access from HTTP (sans "S") loaded resources as long as their loaded from localhost or 127.0.0.1. However I would like to debug my mobile web app accessing my PC on 192.168.0.x is this possible?

I have tried loading the phone via Chrome debugging on the PC via USB but it still falls foul of the restriction. Any ideas?

BTW. The warning message has an "X" which I imagine is remove message but it doesn't work :-(

Comment: This is a real hassle for sure.  You can create an HTTPS server and bypass the warning for IP address.  Or, assign it a hostname like `someproject.test` and put this in your hosts file entry.  I have a self-built tool I use for this which does these things on the fly.  I'll get around to releasing it at some point.  In the mean time, there are other utilities for doing similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only solution I could find: - [Port Forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server#port-forwarding)

You have to be tethered to a USB cable but it works.